# .hover() method strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm trying to build a main menu for a site, so when I hover over `li` of the menu, a `div` will be shown which holds sub menu, which may hold 1 to 3 banners.

This is the code I use to display sub menu when hovering over `li` (this code just tests if hovering event is caught):

```
$('#navigation-menu>li').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
    console.log("HOVERED!");
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    console.log("MOUSELEAVE!");
});
```

I also determine the number of banners in the `div` that will be shown (in my script file this code goes before the hover checking. I also use Bootstrap if it matters.):

```
if(!$.trim($("#banner-3-img").html()).length) {
    if(!$.trim($("#banner-2-img").html()).length) {
        $("#banner-1").addClass("col-sm-12");
        $("#banner-2").css("display","none");
        $("#banner-3").css("display","none");
        console.log("1 BANNER");
        return;
    }
    console.log("2 BANNERS");
    $('#banner-1').addClass("col-sm-6");
    $('#banner-2').addClass("col-sm-6");
    $("#banner-3").css("display","none");

}else{
    console.log("3 BANNERS");
    $("#banner-1").addClass("col-sm-4");
    $("#banner-2").addClass("col-sm-4");
    $("#banner-3").addClass("col-sm-4");
}
```

And this is the `html` part with markup for those banners:

```
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div id="banner-1">
        <a href="#">
            <div id="banner-1-img">
                <img  src="img/mega-menu/banner-1.png" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="banner-2">
        <a href="#">
            <div id="banner-2-img">
                <img  src="img/mega-menu/banner-3-2.png" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="banner-3">
        <a href="#">
            <div id="banner-3-img">
                <img  src="img/mega-menu/banner-3-3.png" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

The strange thing is, when I remove `img` element from `#banner-2-img` and `#banner-3-img`, the script finds that I have only 1 banner (and sets the required class), but the hovering check code doesn't work - I don't get `"HOVERED!"` in the console when hovering over `li`. 
While when I display 2 or 3 banners, I do get the `"HOVERED!"` message.

Nothing else is changed - I only delete the 2 `img` elements from `#banner-2-img` and `#banner-3-img`.

How is this possible?

Comment: Not clear how second code block relates to the first. Create a demo that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Post the html for the menu as well - or create a fiddle/codepen

Comment: And why do you have a `return` statement if there is one banner?

Comment: For starters, I cleaned up your js because it's confusing. In particular, the way that you are checking for an img element and the structure of your conditional statements. https://jsfiddle.net/jbird/3rdw3zg5/

Comment: @Jbird I have `return` so it won't go further as if there are 2 banners.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have no idea why it didn't work from the separate .js file (the link to the script is located at the bottom of the html page and the code was in `$(document).ready()` block), but when I've put the hover-check code in the bottom of the html page, everything worked fine.

```
<script>
(function(){
    $('#navigation-menu>li').on('mouseenter', function () {
        console.log("HOVERED!");
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        console.log("MOUSELEAVE!");
    });
})();
</script>
```